# pg_dump won't run through PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

This question has been addressed in various other posts but they don't seem to help me out.

My issue is that I run the following script from the terminal, the `pg_dump` statement works:

```
$strBK = '/usr/bin/pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "mizk" --no-password  --format plain --data-only --inserts --column-inserts --verbose --file "/home/khalid/tmp/esm/x1" --table "public.\"tblCustomerCategories\"" --table "public.\"tblSellers\"" "dbESM" 2>&1';
    //User has submitted form. Start making backup.
    echo "ok " . shell_exec($strBK);
```

But from php, I get the following error:

```
 ok pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "dbESM" failed:
 fe_sendauth: no password supplied
 pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

As is shown, I'm not asking for the password but the script reports the error about authentication.

My assumption is that PHP runs under `www-data` while the terminal dump runs as the computer user. So how do I fix this issue in a safe way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your theory (`www-data` can't run the command) by running:

```
sudo -iu www-data /usr/bin/pg_dump ...
```

This likely *is* the issue and there are a number of different workarounds with different security ramifications.

- Create a script that runs your dump, owned by your user, with setuid applied (`chmod 4755 <filename>`). Whoever runs this will run it *as* the owner of the file. There are obvious security ramifications if your script is editable by PHP too, or your script is somehow exploitable.
- Use a middle-man. You could write to a file from PHP and read it from a cron-job (running as the right user). If the file exists it runs your dump and deletes the file. This is fairly secure but it's obviously only as instant as your cron interval. Alternatives include things like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which is a bit more industrial for batching or deferring tasks, optionally to other users.
- Beat Postgres into allowing `www-data` access the data. I would suggest doing this through a password but this is still going to allow a hacked `www-data` access to anything you give it.

The `pg_dump` command may also have some peculiarities. There are a few threads around SE that might help with it specifically:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe

Comment: Yes, I tried your method **sudo -iu www-data...** from terminal. It prompts for the password but I get the same error as I do from PHP so that confirms the issue. This is a LAN server so I think I try your first option of using a script.

Comment: Strange... the script works fine from the terminal. But then I tried calling it through PHP like this: **$strBK = '/usr/local/bin/esm-script/export-master.sh';** but I get the same error as before. Did I miss something?

Comment: I wonder if it requires STDIN to work. Try this wrapping the `pg_dump` in a `script` call, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe) inside your script.

Comment: Yes, `script` did the trick but with a bit of ugliness :) ... I had to prefix PGPASSWORD="xxX" before running the pg_dump command. I don't like this too well but I think it's the only (easiest and safest) think to do for the moment. Thanks!